# How do I play multiple animations at once with an MonoGame skinned mesh?

Tags: animation, monogame, mesh

I am working with the SkinnedMesh from [this tutorial](http://what-when-how.com/xna-game-studio-4-0-programmingdeveloping-for-windows-phone-7-and-xbox-360/using-skinnedeffect-xna-game-studio-4-0-programming/).

I am at the point where I want to let my character run (which already works), but when I press the punch key on my keyboard, I only want the upper half of the body to play the punching animations while the lower part of the model continues running. What would I need to change in this example to accomplish this effect?

Comment: XNA has been unsupported since 2013. Maybe it's time to use a more up-to-date framework.

Comment: Actually I am using MonoGame. The tutorial has been written in XNA but monogame adapted XNA so this still should be an "up to date" framework